# What is the probability of 7 numbers picked from 1-30 ending with a different digit?

Tags: probability, combinations, solution-verification

Between 1 and 30, each number with same last digit occurs 3 times.

i) 30C1, Last digit is 0..

ii) 27C1, Last digit is 1..

iii) 24C1, Last digit 2...

iv) 21C1,

v) 18C1,

vi) 15C1,

vii) 12C1,

Possible outcomes: 30C7

Favorable outcomes:  30C1.27C1.24C1.21C1.18C1.15C1.12C1

Probability: 30C1.27C1.24C1.21C1.18C1.15C1.12C1/30C7

Is my answer correct?

Comment: You'll never get repeating last digits with the first card. For the second card, the probability seems to be 27/29: there are 29 cards left, and of those 27 have different last digits. For the third card, the probability is 24/28: there are 28 cards left, and of those 24 have unseen last digits.

Comment: Where did 52C7 come from?  52 does not occur in this problem.  Your answer requires that the first digit be $0$, but even that is $\frac 1{10}$ because there are three cards with $0$ as the last digit.  You miss cases where the first card has last digit $1$ and the second card has last digit $0$ among many others.

Comment: You should consider typing your question in Mathjax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is on the right track, but there are some errors and oversights. It yields the number of ways to pick one card, then a card with a different last digit, then a third card with yet another last digit, and so on. Thus, you’re counting each set of $7$ cards $7!$ times, once for each of the $7!$ orders in which it could have been dealt. In your denominator, however, you’re just counting sets of $7$ cards, without regard for order, and you’re counting sets of $7$ cards from a deck of $52$ cards, not $30$. You must correct the $52$ to $30$ and either divide the numerator by $7!$ to get rid of the overcounting or, equivalently, multiply the denominator by $7!$ to take into account the order in which each hand of $7$ cards is dealt. When you do that, you get

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\binom{30}1\binom{27}1\binom{24}1\binom{21}1\binom{18}1\binom{15}1\binom{12}1}{7!\binom{30}7}&=\frac{30\cdot27\cdot24\cdot21\cdot18\cdot15\cdot12}{7!\binom{30}7}\\
&=\frac{3^7\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}{7!\binom{30}7}\\
&=\frac{3^7\cdot10!}{3!7!\binom{30}7}\\
&=\frac{3^7\binom{10}7}{\binom{30}7}\;.
\end{align*}$$

There is a shorter way to arrive at this result. There are $10$ possible last digits, so there are $\binom{10}7$ ways to choose $7$ of them to be the last digits of a ‘good’ set. There are $3$ cards having each of those $7$ last digits, so once we know what the $7$ last digits are, there are $3^7$ ways to choose the specific $7$ cards having those last digits. Thus, there are $3^7\binom{10}3$ possible ‘good’ hands.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. Can you suggest me some source which will allow me to clear these concepts?

Comment: @Rehab: You’re welcome. I really can’t: I retired long enough ago that I’m no longer very familiar with what’s readily available, and in any case I mostly used my own discussions and explanations when I taught this kind of material, using the text primarily just as a source of problems.